# Greatest integer less than or equal to the 50th term of the series defined below

Tags: sequences-and-series

This question I found in one of my practice papers for the JEE 
$$a_{1}= \sqrt[3]{28}$$ 
and
$$a_{n+1}=\sqrt[3]{a_{n} + 60} \space \space \forall \space n \in\Bbb N $$

Question asks for greatest integer less than or equal to the 50th term of the series defined above.

How to approach this?

Comment: Please, give examples for the "lot" you've tried, add some background, or why you (or us) should care. Otherwise, the question will most likely be closed..

Comment: You couldn't see a pattern in the terms here?  Really?  How many did you compute?

Comment: Is it good to even compute a2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to see that $a_n$ is a strictly increasing sequence and is bounded above by $4$. (Both these facts can be proven via induction.)
This shows that $a_n$ converges. (Of course, as a JEE student, you probably do not care about this and could have assumed this anyway.)

---

Now, let us calculate that limit $L = \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$. Since we know that $(a_n)$ converges, we can take limit on both sides of the recurrece relation to get
$$L = \sqrt[3]{L + 60}.$$
Cube both sides and note that $L = 4$ is the only (real) solution. Thus, $L = 4$.

---

From this we conclude that $a_n < 4$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$. Moreover, since $(a_n)$ was increasing, we have that $a_1 \le a_n$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$.
Noting that $a_1 = \sqrt[3]{28} > \sqrt[3]{27} = 3$, we see that
$$3 < a_n < 4.$$

You can now conclude that the answer is $3$.

Comment: So it's not a question about creating telescopic series . Damn it